# How to do union queries in mssql

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sql-server, azure-sql-database

Hey guys I have some queries that are getting generated dynamically by active record and for performance reasons I need to merge them all together and send them to MSSQL in one go.

I tried the following and it works great in postgresql but I can't get it to work in MSSQL.

```
(SELECT  [panels].* FROM [panels] WHERE [panels].[environment_id] = 14 AND [panels].[agglo_code_id] = 23 AND [panels].[advert_area_id] = 161 AND [panels].[product_id] = 25 AND (NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM campaign_search_panels WHERE campaign_search_panels.panel_id = panels.panel_id AND campaign_search_panels.campaign_id = 65)) AND (NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM "AIDAAU_Avails" WHERE "AIDAAU_Avails"."PanelID" = panels.panel_uid AND "AIDAAU_Avails"."TillDate" >= '08-21-2017' AND "AIDAAU_Avails"."FromDate" <= '09-03-2017'))  ORDER BY [panels].[random_order] ASC OFFSET 0 ROWS FETCH NEXT 3 ROWS ONLY)
UNION ALL
(SELECT  [panels].* FROM [panels] WHERE [panels].[environment_id] = 14 AND [panels].[agglo_code_id] = 23 AND [panels].[advert_area_id] = 136 AND [panels].[product_id] = 25 AND (NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM campaign_search_panels WHERE campaign_search_panels.panel_id = panels.panel_id AND campaign_search_panels.campaign_id = 65)) AND (NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM "AIDAAU_Avails" WHERE "AIDAAU_Avails"."PanelID" = panels.panel_uid AND "AIDAAU_Avails"."TillDate" >= '08-21-2017' AND "AIDAAU_Avails"."FromDate" <= '09-03-2017'))  ORDER BY [panels].[random_order] ASC OFFSET 0 ROWS FETCH NEXT 2 ROWS ONLY)
```

Now I think there are two issues that I can spot already. If I remove the brackets surrounding each query then I get closer but it still complains about ORDER. I have a feeling you can only order after the result but I don't have that much control over how each individual sql query is put together only how i combine them. I would ideally like to keep the ability to both order and have the limit clause for each subquery. Is there any easy way of putting these together so they will work in MSSQL and not just postgres?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: `OFFSET 0 ROWS FETCH FIRST (SELECT 0)` Do you skip entire first resultset? If yes, then what is the point of `UNION ALL` .

Comment: Thanks :) I've fixed that now. In my real example I actually have about 25 of these statements unioned together, some of them returning nothing which I agree is stupid but again it comes from the way the sql is being created. Any idea how to fix the above?

Answer (score 1):

In a UNION query you can only have one ORDER BY clause and it must go at the end:

```
SELECT * from <table1>
UNION ALL
SELECT * from <table2>
ORDER BY <col1>
```

You must remove that ORDER BY on your top query and it should work correctly

Answer (score 0):

If you want to order union results, you would have to throw the results into a CTE. Something like this:

```
with cte_name as
(

select col_1, col_2, etc
from table

union all

select col_1, col_2, etc
from table_2

)

select col_1, col_2
from cte_name
order by col_1
```